# MPI_COMM_SPAWN causing a dead lock

Tags: fortran, mpi

I have an MPI program A that needs to spawn then wait for a different MPI program B to finish. I then need to spawn and wait for program B a second time.

**Program A**

```
      IF (rank .eq. 0) THEN 

         CALL MPI_COMM_SPAWN('prog_b', MPI_ARGV_NULL, size,                &
     &                       MPI_INFO_NULL, 0, MPI_COMM_SELF,              &
     &                       child_comm, MPI_ERRCODES_IGNORE, status)
         WRITE (*,*) 'Parent 1 Before'
         CALL MPI_BARRIER(child_comm, status)
         WRITE (*,*) 'Parent 1 After'

... Change some things ...

         CALL MPI_COMM_SPAWN('prog_b', MPI_ARGV_NULL, size,                &
     &                       MPI_INFO_NULL, 0, MPI_COMM_SELF,              &
     &                       child_comm, MPI_ERRCODES_IGNORE, status)
         WRITE (*,*) 'Parent 2 Before'
         CALL MPI_BARRIER(child_comm, status)
         WRITE (*,*) 'Parent 2 After'

      END IF
```

**Program B**

```
... Wait to finished ...

      CALL MPI_COMM_GET_PARENT(parent_comm, error)
      IF (parent_comm .ne. MPI_COMM_NULL) THEN
         WRITE (*,*) 'Before'
         CALL MPI_BARRIER(parent_comm, error)
         WRITE (*,*) 'After'
      END IF

... Finalize ...
```

When I run this, the first spawning of the program B works fine. But on the second pass, both programs deadlock on the second barrier. I'm spawning 16 instances of program b each time.

**Output**

```
Parent Before 1

... Output of program b ...

Before
Before
Before
Before
Before
Before
Before
Before
Before
Before
Before
Before
Before
After
After
Before
After
Before
After
After
After
After
After
Before
After
After
Parent After 1
After
After
After
After
After
After

... Second call to spawn ...

Parent Before 2

... Output of program b ...

Before
Before
Before
Before
Before
Before
Before
Before
Before
Before
Before
Before
Before
Before
Before
Before
```

As you can see, each process makes it past the first barrier but the second time everything dead locks. I have tried disconnecting the parent and child comms after the first spawn call. I tried merging the parent and child comms and calling barrier on them but nothing seems to fix this deadlock issue.

Comment: First, show how you freed up the communicators. Second, check the error returns. They are there for a reason!

Comment: do you call `MPI_Comm_disconnect()` on the intercomm when it is no more needed ?

Comment: @RussF There is no point in checking the errors because if an error occurred, the program terminated before you have any change to check.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Calling `MPI_COMM_DISCONNECT()` has no effect.